# Akka.DI.Autofac did not create actor

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, akka.net

I am trying to set up DI followed by official akka.net document (http://getakka.net/docs/Dependency%20injection#autofac). However Actors never create. What's wrong in the following my code?

```
public class Worker: ReceiveActor
{
    public Worker()
    {
        Receive<string>(m => Console.WriteLine("Worker is working"));
    }
}

public class WorkerManager : ReceiveActor
{
    public WorkerManager()
    {
        Receive<string>(m => Console.WriteLine("Manager start supervise"));
    }

    protected override void PreStart()
    {
        Context.ActorOf(Context.DI().Props<Worker>(), "Worker1");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Worker>();
        builder.RegisterType<WorkerManager>();

        var system = ActorSystem.Create("DiTestSystem");

        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        IDependencyResolver resolver = new AutoFacDependencyResolver(container, system);
        var manageRef = system.ActorOf(system.DI().Props<WorkerManager>(), "Manager1");

        manageRef.Tell("Hello");
        system.ActorSelection("/user/Manager1/Worker1").Tell("Hello");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When run the code, I got this

[INFO][24/04/2017 1:50:11 AM][Thread 0006][akka://DiTestSystem/user/Manager1/Worker1] Message String from akka://DiTestSystem/deadLetters to akka://DiTestSystem/user/Manager1/Worker1 was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.
Manager start supervise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a race condition. This could happen regardless of whether or not you are creating your actors using a DI container.

When working with an actor system you need to remember that everything happens asynchronously. You code is allowed to continue after sending the message to the `WorkerManager` actor but that does not mean that message has actually been received and processed. It is actually posted to a mailbox for the actor to process on a different thread when it is ready.

It would also be best to not attempt to access the `Worker` actor directly given that you have a `WorkerManager` actor in place. Just like in real life, you would normally ask a manager to organise for some work to be done, and the manager would then in turn decide what workers are required, and assign the necessary work to them.

Akka.NET has a [router feature](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers) that is useful for such scenarios. I have updated your sample code with some additional logging and the router configuration.

```
void Main()
{
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Worker>();
    builder.RegisterType<WorkerManager>();
    var container = builder.Build();

    var system = ActorSystem.Create("DITestSystem");
    var resolver = new AutoFacDependencyResolver(container, system);

    var manager = system.ActorOf(system.DI().Props<WorkerManager>(), "Manager");
    Console.WriteLine("Program: Created Manager");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        manager.Tell("Hello");
    }

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

public class Worker : ReceiveActor
{
    public Worker()
    {
        Receive<string>(m => Console.WriteLine($"Worker {Context.Self.Path.Name} received: {m}"));
    }

    protected override void PreStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"PreStart: {Context.Self.Path}");
    }
}

public class WorkerManager : ReceiveActor
{
    IActorRef worker;

    public WorkerManager()
    {
        Receive<string>(m =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Manager received: {m}");
            worker.Tell(m);
        });
    }

    protected override void PreStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"PreStart: {Context.Self.Path}");

        var props = Context.DI().Props<Worker>().WithRouter(new RoundRobinPool(5));
        worker = Context.ActorOf(props, "Worker");
    }
}
```

Note this line in the `WorkerManager` actor that configures a router for the `Worker` actors.

```
var props = Context.DI().Props<Worker>().WithRouter(new RoundRobinPool(5));
```

This will cause the `ManagerActor` to forward messages to 5 child `Worker` actors in a round-robin manner. The message routing is taken care of for you so there is no need to interact directly with the `Worker` actors.

The sample now also fires off 10 messages to the `ManagerActor` immediately after getting a reference to it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    manageRef.Tell("Hello");
}
```

With more messages in play and some logging you can see that the order of things is not deterministic. This is the output from one run.

```
Program: Created Manager
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$b
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$d
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$f
Worker $b received: Hello
Worker $b received: Hello
Worker $f received: Hello
Worker $f received: Hello
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$c
Worker $c received: Hello
Worker $c received: Hello
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$e
Worker $d received: Hello
Worker $d received: Hello
Worker $e received: Hello
Worker $e received: Hello
```

And this is the output from another.

```
Program: Created Manager
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$b
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$c
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$d
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$f
PreStart: akka://DITestSystem/user/Manager/Worker/$e
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Worker $d received: Hello
Worker $e received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Worker $f received: Hello
Worker $e received: Hello
Manager received: Hello
Worker $f received: Hello
Worker $b received: Hello
Worker $b received: Hello
Worker $c received: Hello
Worker $c received: Hello
Worker $d received: Hello
```

You can see that in the first run the `WorkerManager` had received all messages before creating any child `Worker` actors. In the second run it had created all the child `Worker` actors before receiving any of the messages.

The main point to remember is that it is best to communicate with messages and not make assumptions about when things happen.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. DI container will not create an actor until program send a message to the actor, is it correct?

Comment: The actor system will start to create an instance of the actor when `ActorOf` is called. This will happen on another thread. You can start sending messages as soon as you have the `IActorRef`. These can be delivered to the mailbox for the actor even be before the actor has been fully created on the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

What I found is Actor cannot be created fast enough with Autofac.

When I added Thread.Sleep(20), finally, create actor properly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<WorkerManager>();
    builder.RegisterType<Worker>();

    var system = ActorSystem.Create("DiTestSystem");

    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    IDependencyResolver resolver = new AutoFacDependencyResolver(container, system);
    var manageRef = system.ActorOf(system.DI().Props<WorkerManager>(), "Manager1");

    Thread.Sleep(20); // ADDED THIS LINE
    manageRef.Tell("Hello");
    system.ActorSelection("/user/Manager1/Worker1").Tell("Hello");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I think it is quite big problem, because this approach cannot guarantee actor always create/resolve during sleep time.

I keep open this problem, because I think it cannot be a proper answer.